# Why is my sticky nav not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried everything and this sticky nave won't work. You can skip the CSS and go straight to the HTML, which has the jQuery I'm trying to use to achieve this.

Code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* Logo */

.entirelogo {
  z-index: 100;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 105;
}

#conceal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 104;
}


/* End Logo */


/*                               Navigation                          */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
}

#main_nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 103;
}

ul {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  padding: 20px 25px 25px 25px;
  z-index: 30;
  position: relative;
  top: 5;
}


/*Dropdown Menu*/

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 25;
}

.dropbtn {
  padding: 45px 0 35px 0px;
  margin: -45px 40px -35px 40px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-20em);
  z-index: -100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.5s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: -250;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -250;
}


/*Dropdown links hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/*Dropdown menu hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: -10;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.5s;
}


/*Color of dropdown button when dropdown content shown */

.dropdown:hover {
  color: #6d9dc5;
}

#main-nav-scrolled {
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}


/*                           End Navigation                          */


/*
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
*/
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JAM Bakery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Gloria+Hallelujah|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    var mn = $("main-nav");
    mns = $("main-nav-scrolled");

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 275) {
        mn.addClass(mns);
      } else {
        mn.removeClass(mns);
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Nav-->
  <div class="entirelogo">
    <p id="conceal"></p>
    <center><img class="logo" src="Pictures/Jam_Bakery.png" width="312.5" height="250"></center>
  </div>
  <nav class="main_nav">
    <ul>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropbtn">Products</li>
        <ul class=dropdown-content>
          <li><a href="cupcakes.html">Cupcakes</a></li>
          <li><a href="cakes.html">Cakes</a></li>
          <li><a href="bagles.html">Bagles</a>
            <li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <li class="buttons"><a href="aboutus.html" class="btn">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="buttons"><a href="contactus.html" class="btn">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!--End Nav-->
  <br>
  <div class="content">
    <p>wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your above code.

First, your element has the class `main_nav`, yet you are trying to target it with `$("main-nav")`. Target it with `$(".main_nav")` instead.

Second, you're trying to add the class `main-nav-scrolled`, which is actually written as an **ID** in your CSS (`#main-nav-scrolled`). Change that to a class selector:

```
.main-nav-scrolled {
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Finally, you can target directly, avoiding the need for variables at all:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 275) {
    $(".main_nav").addClass('main-nav-scrolled');
  } else {
    $(".main_nav").removeClass('main-nav-scrolled');
  }
});
```

I've updated your code to provide a working copy:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* Logo */

.entirelogo {
  z-index: 100;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 105;
}

#conceal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 104;
}


/* End Logo */


/*                               Navigation                          */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
}

#main_nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 103;
}

ul {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  padding: 20px 25px 25px 25px;
  z-index: 30;
  position: relative;
  top: 5;
}


/*Dropdown Menu*/

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 25;
}

.dropbtn {
  padding: 45px 0 35px 0px;
  margin: -45px 40px -35px 40px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-20em);
  z-index: -100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.5s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: -250;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -250;
}


/*Dropdown links hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/*Dropdown menu hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: -10;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.5s;
}


/*Color of dropdown button when dropdown content shown */

.dropdown:hover {
  color: #6d9dc5;
}

.main-nav-scrolled {
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}


/*                           End Navigation                          */


/*
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
*/
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JAM Bakery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Gloria+Hallelujah|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    var mn = $("main-nav");
    mns = "main-nav-scrolled";

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 275) {
      $(".main_nav").addClass('main-nav-scrolled');
      } else {
        $(".main_nav").removeClass('main-nav-scrolled');
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Nav-->
  <div class="entirelogo">
    <p id="conceal"></p>
    <center><img class="logo" src="Pictures/Jam_Bakery.png" width="312.5" height="250"></center>
  </div>
  <nav class="main_nav">
    <ul>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropbtn">Products</li>
        <ul class=dropdown-content>
          <li><a href="cupcakes.html">Cupcakes</a></li>
          <li><a href="cakes.html">Cakes</a></li>
          <li><a href="bagles.html">Bagles</a>
            <li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <li class="buttons"><a href="aboutus.html" class="btn">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="buttons"><a href="contactus.html" class="btn">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!--End Nav-->
  <br>
  <div class="content">
    <p>wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
      wifjoadshfguiowADHSBFJIOWAHJSDBFIOUAWADHJSBFIOUQahjksbdfidoasaDHBIODASbcnxhjisoakBCHVKIOaksbchxkiosacnvx
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```